# Problemas ao tentar enviar e-mail pelo servidor smtp

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação a qual envia e-mails pelo servidor smtp.gmail.com.

Quando estou conectado a uma rede comum, funciona perfeitamente. Mas, pela rede da minha empresa ocorre o seguinte erro:

> System.Net.WebException: Impossível conectar-se ao servidor remoto ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu\r\ncorretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou\r\nporque o host conectado não respondeu 64.233.186.108:587\r\n   em System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)\r\n   em System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)\r\n   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---\r\n   em System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)\r\n   em System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)\r\n   em System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)\r\n   em System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)\r\n   em System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)\r\n   em System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)\r\n   em System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()\r\n   em System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)"

Estou usando a porta 587 e deixei o EnableSsl = true

Isso pode ser por causa do proxy da rede da empresa?

Segue o trecho do código responsável pelas configurações:

```
MailMessage mensagemEmail = new MailMessage();
mensagemEmail.From = new MailAddress(Remetente, "Novo Registro");
mensagemEmail.Subject = Assunto;
mensagemEmail.Body = enviaMensagem;
mensagemEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
client.EnableSsl = true;

NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(StringsProjeto.remetente, StringsProjeto.pass);
client.Credentials = cred;

client.Send(mensagemEmail);
```

Comment: Você já liberou o acesso à aplicativos menos seguros no Gmail?

Comment: Sim, amigo. Já liberei o acesso aos aplicativos menos seguros :(

Comment: Então o problema é, como você já disse, o proxy.

Comment: Configurei uma exceção para o smtp.gmail.com, mas também não funcionou. Existe alguma outra configuração necessária?

Comment: Não faço ideia, nem sei que tipo de proxy/firewall é usado aí. Tem que ver com quem configurou a rede.

Comment: ja tentou usando a porta 465?

Comment: Sim, @MarconcilioSouza. Mas também não deu certo.

Comment: Já tive esse problema para enviar email para um cliente, e a unica forma foi utilizando uma biblioteca de terceiros. o problema ocorria devido o tipo de segurança e só aceitava o STARTTLS, usei  o MailKit https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/ veja se ajuda.

Comment: http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient.htm

Comment: @Leandor, conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @PabloVargas, consegui! Foi através do pessoal que administra a rede da empresa. Eles disseram que o servidor estava bloqueando mesmo. Obrigado pelas sugestões. Abs!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema através do pessoal que administra a rede da empresa. Eles disseram que o servidor estava bloqueando.